# Displaying Friends with Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

On my website I would like to display the users Facebook friends, using the Facebook Javascript SDK. When loading the asynchronous script, I use this code :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {               
  FB.init({appId: 'MYAPPID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

  FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
      var divTarget=document.getElementById("friends-list-container");
      var data=response.data;
      for (var friendIndex=0; friendIndex<data.length; friendIndex++)
    {
           var divContainer = document.createElement("div");
           divContainer.innerHTML="<b>" + data[friendIndex].name + "</b>";
           divTarget.appendChild(divContainer);
    }
  });  
};
```

I think I have asked for the right perms: 'friends_about_me', but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Best, 
Newben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't need to ask for `friends_about_me` to get friends of the user, but you for sure should authorize the user (which is not done in the code you provided), also due to asynchronous nature of `status` retrieval you must ensure user is already logged in prior to fetching his friends.

Also it wouldn't hurt to add some error checking in your `callback`:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
      if (response && response.data){
        // Handle response
      } else {
        console.log('Something goes wrong', response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes I put this code, and it works. In fact, the <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"...> suffices to show me if the user is logged. What do you mean exactely by authorize the user ? Best

Comment: @Newben, If you're using `login-button` it's ok and will fulfill the authentication flow (which I've pointed as missing in your code) ;)

Comment: Okay, in fact I wrapped the fb.api call in a  FB.getLoginStatus part and it worked. In fact I didn't understood that the user must be authorized ! thanks, Newben